# Iterate through environments in GitLab CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a .gitlab-ci.yml pipeline with a simple job that needs to run in several environments. Something similar to the following:

```
test:v1.0:
  stage: test
  environment:
    name: v1.0
  tags:
    - v1.0
  script:
    - ./run.sh $VERSION

test:v2.0:
  stage: test
  environment:
    name: v2.0
  tags:
    - v2.0
  script:
    - ./run.sh $VERSION

test:v2.5:
  stage: test
  environment:
    name: v2.5
  tags:
    - v2.5
  script:
    - ./run.sh $VERSION
```

Does GitLab have any kind of mechanism to create a job by iterating an array? Something similar to [Ansible's loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html). The idea is to avoid copy-pasting the same job over and over, when only environment or runner tag changes. I couldn't see anything in documentation, and all feature requests about this topic seem closed. Is there any workaround to achieve the same behaviour and accepted as best practice by the community?

I know from other questions here that one proposed solution could be:

```
test:all:
  stage: test
  script:
    - Iterate here with v1.0, v2.0, v2.5, etc
```

The issue with this approach is that only one job is created, also you lose the ability to choose runners and other capabilities from GitLab environments feature, so I'd rather avoid this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the possibility of using variables in `tags` which was implemented just recently and the use of a [parallel matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallel) you can do the following:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./run.sh $VERSION
  environment:
    name: $VERSION
  tags:
    - $VERSION
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - VERSION: [v1.0, v2.0, v3.0]
```

This will create a job for the three defined versions and each job will run in parallel.